# how to fix connectivity problems with arduino board on ubuntu 16.04

Tags: drivers, ubuntu-drivers, arduino

I need to use the CP210 driver for the Arduino IDE on my ubuntu 16.04.
I initially tried to install the driver but were getting lots of errors but I believe the driver is actually already installed

```
ls -al /lib/modules/"$(uname -r)"/kernel/drivers/usb/serial/cp210x.ko
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 59126 Oct 15 18:24 /lib/modules/4.15.0-122-generic/kernel/drivers/usb/serial/cp210x.ko
```

I guess it might be a communication issue but I am not sure how to fix this. When I plug in my board the Arduino IDE shows /dev/ttyUSB0 (Silicon labs) as serial port but my code doesn't work and suggests a problem with the board driver.
The arduino documentation says I need ‘dev/tty.usbserial-0001 (Silicon Labs)’ or ‘COM3 (Silicon Labs)’ and need to download a CP210 driver

Any help greatly appreciated !

Comment: What exactly is not working? Uploading code to the board from Arduino IDE? What exact board are you using? Please explain as detailed as possible what you tried, and what the results were, so we can try to give more specific help.

Answer (score 0):

There's a number of things to try here. Since you don't specify what exact board you are using, the following are some general hints, either one of those or none may help:

- Make sure you are using a known-good USB cable and USB port. USB 3.0 ports often don't work well with those boards.
- Verify how to put your board in bootloader mode. Sometimes Arduino IDE doesn't do it automatically.
- Also, depending on how the board is designed, it may switch ports when going into the bootloader.
- Make sure your user is allowed to write to the port by setting up appropriate udev rules and permissions - see [here](https://playground.arduino.cc/Linux/All/)  for general hints or [here](https://learn.adafruit.com/usbtinyisp/avrdude#for-linux-632097-7) for a particular board, but which may be adaptable to others.
- Try removing modemmanager as explained [here](https://learn.adafruit.com/adafruit-arduino-ide-setup/linux-setup), it may interfere with the communication as well.